# How to extract MS Office for Mac keys from my Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: macos, mac, snow-leopard, ms-office

I have an old Mac Air 1,1 that has Office for Mac 2011 installed on it. I paid for the software and it installed the version on my machine. I don't have access to my live.microsoft.com account anymore and there's no way for me to get MicroSoft people/support to give me the keys again.

I need a way to extract the keys from my current installation of Office on my mac. For instance, in Windows, the keys used to be loaded in the registry at a certain place, under a certain key. Some programs could fetch them for you. Is there any such way I can do it for a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this one works for all applications, mainly because there is no set standard to store product keys, but [Mac Product Key Finder](https://mac-product-key-finder.com/) should work for you. Its how I got Photoshop and others off my school mac onto my personal.

Comment: That program can get the Office 2008 licenses; but, not 2011 which the user requested.